# react redux - pass data multiple levels down

Tags: reactjs, redux

very new to redux here, can't find any similar examples online of what i want to achieve, maybe i have what redux does confused. Say i have something like this i've simplified

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { articles: state.articles };
};

const ConnectedList = ({ articles }) => (
  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    <ConnectedListItems {...articles}/>
  </ul>
);

const ConnectedListItems = ({articles}) =>{
  // maybe render here or pass articles to another component
}

const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);
export default List;
```

Is there some way i can just pass straight to ConnectedListItems, I feel like i'm prop drilling atm. ConnectedList doesn't need articles, ConnectedList may be a class as well

Thanks

Comment: You can simply connect the component in which you want to access the redux store data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `mapStateToProps` for **ConnectedListItems** component also as you did for the **ConnectedList** Component.

***Change Required:-***

```
let ConnectedListItems = ({articles}) =>{
  // maybe render here or pass articles to another component
}
let ConnectedListItems = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedListItems);
```

***Updated Code:-***

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { articles: state.articles };
};

const ConnectedList = ({ articles }) => (
  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    <ConnectedListItems />
  </ul>
);

let ConnectedListItems = ({articles}) =>{
  // maybe render here or pass articles to another component
}

ConnectedListItems = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedListItems);

const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);
export default List;
```

Comment: Just what i needed, cheers